# li:last-child formatting an inner div

Tags: css

Warning...  not the sharpest tool in the CSS toolbox here...

I'm trying to write a tree control using ULs...  and stuck on a CSS issue.  To simplify the question, I boiled down the example to something that might not make sense, but the essence of the CSS issue is as simple as possible.

Consider this html:

```
<ul>
    <li><div>should be green :)</div>
        <ul>
            <li><div>should be green :)</div></li>
            <li><div>should be red :)</div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><div>should be red :)</div>
        <ul>
            <li><div>should be green !!!!!!!!!!!!</div></li>
            <li><div>should be red :)</div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this CSS:

```
ul li{
    background-color: green;
}

ul li:last-child div{
    background-color: red;
}
```

The one item that says:

```
<li><div>should be green !!!!!!!!!!!!</div></li>
```

Appears red instead of green!!!!!

Since the div that contains it is contained in an LI that is NOT the last in the list, I expected it to use the normal selector instead of the last-child selector

Here is a fiddle for your reputation point seeking pleasure!

http://jsfiddle.net/dmd1214/5Vm58/16/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) for selecting the last element(div) of `li`.

```
ul li:last-child > div{
    background-color: red;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/5Vm58/18/)

Answer (score 3):

Make your descendant selector a child selector:

```
ul li:last-child > div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

That way, it matches only the `<div>` elements that are children of that last `<li>` element.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5Vm58/20/**

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are targeting a `div` with your `:last-child` usage.

```
ul  li {
    background-color: green;
}

ul li:last-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Vm58/19/

Comment: I do need the contained div to be targeted... but my example did not show why.  Thanks though!